# How to printk with IP address or MAC address in Linux Kernel Source Code

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel

I have to change TCP Congestion Control algorithm a little bit by modifying Linux Kernel Source Code. But to check if the result is correct, I need to log info of MAC or IP address.

I used PRINTK function to print messages for kernel. But I feel hard to print out MAC/IP address of hosts.

> printk("%pM \n", mac)

But what is mac refer to?
In TCP source code, I often work with skbuff or sock struct.

Thank you.

UPDATE:

```
struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);
printk(KERN_DEBUG "%pI4", iph->saddr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Linux documents the `printk` format specifier extensions in the file `Documentation/printk-formats.txt` available as part of the kernel's source code. For your example,

```
IPv4 addresses:

        %pI4    1.2.3.4
        %pi4    001.002.003.004
        %p[Ii][hnbl]

        For printing IPv4 dot-separated decimal addresses. The 'I4' and 'i4'
        specifiers result in a printed address with ('i4') or without ('I4')
        leading zeros.
```

The parameter passed would be a pointer to the IP address to print (skbuff, socket structure, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
from arch/xtensa/platforms/iss/network.c:

```
printk("(%pM) ", lp->mac);
```

i found it using this command

```
grep -R "mac)" * | grep printk
```

It might be easier to help if you could tell us which file/line you are currently working on.