# How to print correctly a IP using NETFILTER in C

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ip, netfilter

I have the following code, it only catch the packets and prints the IP source and destination:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;

unsigned int hook_func(void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state) {
    struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
    unsigned int src_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->saddr;
    unsigned int dest_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->daddr;
    printk(KERN_INFO "IPs: %u \t to \t %u \n", src_ip, dest_ip);
    return NF_ACCEPT;   
}

int init_module() { /* Fill in our hook structure */
    nfho.hook = hook_func; /* Handler function */
    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING; /* First hook for IPv4 */
    nfho.pf = PF_INET;
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST; /* Make our function first */
    nf_register_hook(&nfho);
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module() {
    nf_unregister_hook(&nfho);
}
```

But, I don't know how to print it correctly (like a IP X.X.X.X) because it shows the following information:

> IPs: 16777343      to  16842879
>
> IPs: 4198316624  to  67108884
>
> IPs: 16842879  to  16777343

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to printk with IP address or MAC address in Linux Kernel Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584913/how-to-printk-with-ip-address-or-mac-address-in-linux-kernel-source-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%pI4` for the format specifier.

e.g. `printk(KERN_DEBUG "IPs: %pI4 \t to \t %pI4 \n", &src_ip, &dest_ip);`

This is documented in Documentation/printk-formats.txt.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can you inet_ntoa function to get the readable IP address: https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The is a question about kernel space, see the [linux-kernel] tag, the linux-specific `#include`s, the `printk(KERN_INFO` etc. Therefore your answer is just wrong as the linked-to documentation is for user space.